# use both UIViewAnimationOption

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

Why can use both 2 `UIViewanimation` like: `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`
and when use it what animation use first (priority) and how can know it?Thanks :D

Comment: Look up bitwise operators.

Comment: bitwise operator i know but i want know what animation use first if i put them in to transition view function Thanks :D